# Laravel blade pages are not loaded

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I really need your help.
I have a project made with laravel 5.2 and it works fine in my computer but when I move it to another computer it does not show all blade pages except generic html
The question I have originally posted on Laracasts: [My question link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/blade-view-are-not-showing)

The page being rendered is:

```
<div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
            <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                                    <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
                        <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
                        <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr> in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 347" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ClassLoader.php line 347</a>:</span>
                        <span class="exception_message">Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!</span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="block">
                        <ol class="traces list_exception">
   <li> in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 347" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ClassLoader.php line 347</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException">FatalErrorException</abbr>->__construct() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php line 133" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">HandleExceptions.php line 133</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->fatalExceptionFromError() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php line 118" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">HandleExceptions.php line 118</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions">HandleExceptions</abbr>->handleShutdown() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php line 0" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">HandleExceptions.php line 0</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader">ClassLoader</abbr>->findFileWithExtension() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 329" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ClassLoader.php line 329</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader">ClassLoader</abbr>->findFile() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php line 300" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ClassLoader.php line 300</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader">ClassLoader</abbr>->loadClass() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php line 0" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Application.php line 0</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>spl_autoload_call() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php line 648" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Application.php line 648</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Application">Application</abbr>->registerDeferredProvider() in <a title="D:\accounting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php line 628" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Application.php line 628</a></li>
   <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Application">Application</abbr>->loadDeferredProvider() in <a title="D:\accounting\v
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error being shown on the page, you are reaching a maximum function nesting level error; `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached`.

To solve this you just need to increase the value of `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in your `php.ini`. You can increase this to whatever you want, 200 or 300 should do the trick.

Note, this is usually only an error when you are in local development due to using xdebug to help the debugging process as you build things.

More on the max nesting level below:

http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level